# Django views not returning a value from a multiple parameter request?

Tags: reactjs, django

I've been using vanilla Django as a backend to my React frontend. I'm trying to make a POST request using axios that passes a dictionary of 2 values to my django view, and so far on my front end the values are valid, the connection to the django url is made, but the only issue is the actual data being processed in the view. If I try to print the value, it returns as None. Heres what I have so far:

### Relevant Code

views.py

```
def render_data(request):
    reddit_url = request.POST.get('reddit_url')
    sort = request.POST.get('sort')
    print(reddit_url, sort)
    users_data, count = run_data(reddit_url, sort)
    data = {
        'users_data': users_data,
        'count': count,
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

component.jsx

```
const APIcall = () => {
    axios
      .post(
        `http://127.0.0.1:8000/reddit_data/`,
        {
          reddit_url: location.state.link,
          sort: location.state.sort,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-CSRFToken": location.state.token,
          },
          withCredentials: true, //cors requests
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("YESSIR");
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

### Expected/actual output

Ideally, the output would print the values from the request, but the actual result is just `None, None`.

### What I tried

1. I tried using `request.POST['reddit_url']` with no different results
2. Double checking the frontend values to make sure the POST call is going through with the correct values
3. I'll be honest I havent tried much I really cant understand this one

Comment: Try to print `request.method` and `request.POST`

Comment: I used `"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` for my header, which returned a QueryDict in my django console, however I still can't grab the values. They return as `<QueryDict: {'{"url":"https://old.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/pa5b2h/at_least_tell_me_atta_boy/","sort":"top"}': ['']}>` which doesn't seem to be the right format.

Comment: And with `application/json` it's nothing?

Comment: I solved it, I'll update my main post. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, my `QueryDict` was returning empty in my Django console while trying to print it, and I simply solved it by using `var formData = new FormData()`; appending my values, then using it as a parameter in my axios post to make a POST request.